# How can I get the username from a python script run with pkexec?

Tags: 14.04, python, pkexec

I'm executing a python script as root with pkexec and I'm using `working_dir = os.getenv('HOME')` to get the username but it always returns `root` instead of `test1` which is the current user.
How can I get the user that ran pkexec instead?

I already tried `print os.environ["SUDO_USER"]` but that fails since it's not being executed directly with sudo. I am on trusty now but behaves the same in 16.04.

Comment: AFAIK the only environment variable inherited from the invoking user is `PKEXEC_UID`, so you'd need to find a (non evil) way to derive the home directory from that

Comment: Thanks, using `print os.environ["PKEXEC_UID"]` I managed to get the normal user's uid. I just need to get the name of the user from the uid and this should solve my problem which is less complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
import pwd
import os

user = pwd.getpwuid(int(os.environ["PKEXEC_UID"])).pw_name
working_dir = '/home/{}'.format(user)
```